# Powershell: Copy and modify filename

Tags: powershell, filenames

I have a requirement to copy files from a network drive to local drive based on minutes. Once copied over then I need to modify the filename as per below requirements:

Sample filename:

Ser1-PRD-CL4$Entreprise_AG2_MyCompany-NA_DB_Name_02_LOG_20191217_094501.trn

1. Copy all files created 35 minutes ago from a Network Directory e.g. \Server\Path to Local directory D:\NameofDB
   (I was able to achieve the copy part but wondering if there is any flag that I should put to prevent the same file being copied over again, the copied file will have their name modified so not sure how we can track that)
2. Once copied modify the name of all copied only files as following:

   a. Remove all characters appearing before word "MyCompany"

   b. Remove underscore along with word LOG   "_LOG"

   c. Remove  underscore (_) between date and transaction number: 20191217_094501

I have achieved the copy and removal of "_LOG" from the filenames but having trouble with the remaining requirement.

Any input will be appreciated:

Important Note: There will be other files in the destination that were moved name and have their names modified in the destination directory and those file names should not be modified.

```
$Sourcefolder= "D:\Temp"
$Targetfolder= "D:\Temp2"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Sourcefolder -Recurse|
Where-Object {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60)
}| Copy-Item -Destination $Targetfolder
Get-ChildItem -Path $Targetfolder | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "_LOG", ""} 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Targetfolder | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^MyCompany'} #This is not working
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question on the repeated copying of the same files see: [Powershell script that can log already scanned files and ignore them on next run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380819/powershell-script-that-can-log-already-scanned-files-and-ignore-them-on-next-run)

For 2a)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Targetfolder | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.substring($_.Name.indexof("MyCompany"))}
```

Please notice that the string is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, although it is working but the code is creating lots of duplicate files. I guess rename retains the original filename I guess? May split or trim function would do better in this case?

Comment: @Ali `rename-item` does not retain the old file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Copy-Item to specify a new name *while* copying (so no need to rename afterwards).  Look at the code below to get the idea:

```
$Sourcefolder= "D:\Temp"
$Targetfolder= "D:\Temp2"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Sourcefolder -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        $_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60)
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $newname = $_.Name.Replace('_LOG','')                       # removes _LOG  
        $newname = $newname -Replace "(\d)_(\d)","$1$2"             # replace underscore between the digits
        $newname = $newname -Replace "(.*)Mycompany","MyCompany$1"  # gets rid of anything before the word "MyCompany"
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination (Join-Path $Targetfolder $newname)
    }
```

Comment: This sounds promising, can you please also add the third requirement for removing everything before the string "MyCompany".

Comment: I updated the answer.  Mind you, there must be a nicer way to do this, but I'm no regex expert.  What I wrote will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm getting the following error: 

Copy-Item : Cannot find path 
'D:\Temp2\Ser1-PRD-CL4$Entreprise_AG2_MyCompany-NA_DB_Name_LOG_20191218_074502.trn' 
because it does not exist.
At line:10 char:9
+         Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination (Join-Path $Targetfolder $newname)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Temp2\Ser1-P...1218_074502.trn:String) [ 
   Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: Yeap it does exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying it here with regex lookahead and lookbehind https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html, so `-replace` only gets rid of the part that actually matches.

```
dir | 
copy-item -destination { 
  $_.name -replace '.*(?=MyCompany)' -replace '_LOG' -replace '(?<=\d)_(?=\d)' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target 
Item:        /Users/js/foo/MyServer$Entreprise_AG2_MyCompany-NA_DB_Name_LOG_20191217_094501.trn 
Destination:                         /Users/js/foo/MyCompany-NA_DB_Name_20191217094501.trn".
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
get-childitem-path "\\server\share\path" -recurse | foreach {
  if ($_.LastWriteTime -gt [DateTime]::NowAddMinutes(-60)) {
    $TheName = $_.Name -replace "_LOG", ""
    $TheName = $TheName -replace "\d_\d", "$1$2"
    $TheName = $TheName -replace ".*MyCompany", "MyCompany"
    Copy-Item -path $_ -destination {join-path "TargetPath" $TheName}
  }
}
```