# Move only New files to a different directory - Powershell

Tags: powershell

Running the following in powershell. Goal is to move files from folder 2 to folder 1, but only new files. Also would like to know which files were moved, sort like a log file if possible

Here is what i have so far :

```
 $DownloadFolder = 'C:\FOLDER1' 

 $KeepFolder = 'C:\folder2'

 $DownloadFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $DownloadFolder


    $KeepFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $KeepFolder
    $FileDiffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DownloadFiles -DifferenceObject $KeepFiles
    $FileDiffs | foreach {
    $copyParams = @{
     'path' = $_.InputObject.Fullname
       }
 $Downloadll = $copyParams.path
 if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>')
  {
   Copy-Item $Downloadll -Destination $KeepFolder   -force
 }
}
```

Trying to compare folder 1 and folder 2 and move ONLY new files to folder1. But getting the following error:

```
  "" Cannot overwrite with the item filename.txt   with itself
```

Comment: this should be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380819/powershell-script-that-can-log-already-scanned-files-and-ignore-them-on-next-run/59380980#59380980

Comment: Why is there a colon after $downloadfolder on the first line?

Comment: It's spelled wrong also.

Comment: sorry - typed too fast

Comment: I think you want `<=` not `=>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look into using the "robocopy" command.

It can move the newer files only, and it gives you the log you wanted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy
https://serverfault.com/questions/129098/how-to-get-robocopy-running-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

There is a colon after $downloadfolder on the first line.

It's spelled wrong also.

You want `<=` not `=>`.  Otherwise it tries to copy to the first folder.

Add `-passthru` to copy-item to get the output.